# Does Laravel seeder overwrite the entire table

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-seeding

Does Laravel seeder overwrite the entire table or is it possible to just make it add to the table without modifying existing content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeder usually just adds some data. It's just a simple class which does something like this:

```
// Insert one row of random data into the 'users' table
DB::table('users')->insert([
    'name' => str_random(10),
    'email' => str_random(10).'@gmail.com',
    'password' => bcrypt('secret'),
]);
```

So no, it will not overwrite anything if you'll not tell it to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel seeder will not overwrite the table by default, it will just append. You could write functionality if you wanted to `truncate` the table prior to seeding.

Answer (score 0):

To create migration of seeding use the following laravel package
https://github.com/slampenny/SmartSeeder

It creates versioned seeding and will only seed new files that are not migrated just like the default table migrations